# Server Error in '/' Application when trying to duplicate a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to duplicate an existing div so when I click my button I
expect the 'duplicate' div I currently have to be created again underneath it
so Now there will be two of those divs and If I was to click the button
again there will be 3 and so on..

but when I click the button I see the div being created for about
half a second and then the page drops me the following error:

***Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.***

Here is my XAML code:

```
 <div id="duplicater">
         <div id="gamestype">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>type</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="gamestype" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="92px"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td>name of game: </td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="namegame" runat="server" Height="17px" Width="118px"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
        </table>   
    </div>
    </div>

 <button id="button" onclick="duplicate()">Add new game</button>
```

Here is my Javascript code:

```
  <script>
        document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;

        var i = 0;
        var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

        function duplicate() {
            var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
            clone.id = "duplicater" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
            original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
        }
    </script>
```

maybe the problem could be to do with MVC when the button is clicked it has no post or something I'm not quite sure as I am really new to mvc, but any suggestions why I get the error stated above.

Comment: Error in document.getElementById('duplicater') . The id is "duplicate" without R

Comment: Yes that was a typo I actually have the R in duplicater in my program and it doesn't work, thanks for the spot though I shall edit the post now

Comment: Its an mvc project I am using the asp view engine instead of Razor

Comment: @user3668266 Thanks, you also need to realise that ASP.NET will create an ID for `gamestype` and `namegame`. Duplicating these elements will also duplicate their IDs

Comment: yes, I did always have that in mind, could you suggest anyway to get around that?

Comment: Is the button in a form? (By default `<button>` elements are submit buttons, so if your button is there just to trigger some JS you should add `type="button"`.)

Comment: your code is working perfectly in fiddle. So this problem is coming because of other code you have surrounded it.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks that has now stopped dropping the error. However, when I duplicate the div It places the duplicated div below the original div but ontop of the other divs I have on the page, any suggestions?

Comment: user3668266 please check your css for the last question To position one Div over the other you use the z-index on the css, together with position: absolute or relative or fixed

Some examples:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

On the container that you like to be front set a bigger z-index than the containers that you like to be on back.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is MVC? MVC doesn't use asp:TextBox runat="server"

Comment: @Izekid That doesn't work still creates the duplicated div at the bottom of the page